# Failed to create a P2P device interface p2p-dev-wlan0

Tags: archlinux

I am trying to get my raspberry pi 3 running arch linux, to miracast to an android phone. I am using the pi as the sink, but I am having trouble setting up the p2p network. Running iw list, tells me that the pi is capable of p2p networking, so I dont quite understand the above issue.

If anyone has any advice, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue today with my raspberryPi 3 running Archlinux. As it turns out another instance of wpa_supplicant was already running. Once this was killed it worked,